# Finding $t(r,\mu)$ for $t\left (\frac{2\mu}{3}-\mu r \right )+t^2 \left (\frac{\mu}{4}-\frac{\mu r}{3} \right )+...=r-\mu$

Tags: analysis

For example, if I have:

$$t\left (\frac{2\mu}{3}-\mu r \right )=r-\mu$$

I find very easily what is $t(r,\mu)$:

$$t(r,\mu)=\frac{r-\mu}{ \left (\frac{2\mu}{3}-\mu r \right ) }$$

Now, I need to find the whole expression what is $t(r,\mu)$ in this case below:
$$t\left (\frac{2\mu}{3}-\mu r \right )+t^2 \left (\frac{\mu}{4}-\frac{\mu r}{3} \right )+t^3 \left (\frac{\mu}{15}-\frac{\mu r}{12} \right )=r-\mu$$

Any help about this would mean a lot for me.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question but if it is a cubic equation in $t$ you can solve it explicitly ([here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5Bt+((2+%5C%5BMu%5D)%2F3+-+r+%5C%5BMu%5D)+%2B+t%5E2+(%5C%5BMu%5D%2F4+-+(r+%5C%5BMu%5D)%2F3)+%2B+t%5E3+(%5C%5BMu%5D%2F15+-+(r+%5C%5BMu%5D)%2F12)+%3D%3D+r+-+%5C%5BMu%5D,t%5D) for example). The result is not very nice however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a follow up to the comment by @Delta-u...Using *Mathematica* one gets the following solutions to the cubic equation:

```
FullSimplify[Solve[t (2 m/3 - m r) + t^2 (m/4 - m r/3) + t^3 (m/15 - m r/12) == r - m, t]]
```

[image: Solution to cubic equation]